# Tuple and vector. What do I have here?

Tags: notation, vectors

For a cluster analysis I have elements with two features/attributes. The first feature is in $\mathbb R$ and bounded to the interval $[0,1]$ and the second feature is in $\mathbb N$.

Is it ok to speak of a feature vector $\vec v_i$ for each element $i$. Or is it just a tuple $v_i$ for each element?

Comment: It seems to me that your elements are "objects" in the "space" $\mathbb R \times \mathbb N$, i.e. are ordered pairs $(x,n)$ such that : $x \in \mathbb R$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. They form a set $\{ (x,n) : x \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N \}$.

Comment: To expand upon @MauroALLEGRANZA's comment, as long as you cannot _do_ anything to or with your objects (either some form of multiplication, or there are specific functions between them that have some property (think continuity) or something like that), then your objects are just sets, or ordered pairs. Once there is some _structure_ involved, you can start categorizing exactly what it is you have more specifically.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That is correct. So according to what you wrote can I assume that ordered pair is equal to a feature 2-tuple? So it is not a vector?

Comment: @Arthur During the cluster analysis the elements are compared by a distance function. So each feature $i$ of an element $x$ is compared with the same feature $i$ of another element $y$. The comparison is done by $abs(x-y)$. Does this make any difference to my initial question and on how you call the features (tuple or vector)?

Comment: Can you identify the salient difference between tuple and vector in your problem domain?

Comment: @EricTowers I read that a vector is a special case of a n-tuple where each element (in my case feature/attribute) of the tuple belongs to the same class of objects (so e.g. $\mathbb R$). Because here I have $\mathbb R$ for the first feature and $\mathbb N$ for the second I don't know if I should call it a vector or tuple.

Comment: It's not a vector, technically. @user2653422

Comment: @afedder Thank you. Could you please explain why it's not a vector?

Comment: As you said, vectors (a specific type of tuple) must have all objects of the same class. Here, you have two objects that are not of the same class.

Comment: There's absolutely no problem referring to your tuple as a vector as long as you're clear and unambiguous about what it is. The word 'vector' is already used in many ways in mathematics and there is no one single canonical definition. Your proposed definition is close enough to some existing uses that it's a natural choice. But your use of the word is unlikely to confuse anyone.